# How secure is AutoHotkey

Tags: windows

On the web page of AutoHotkey they put the following information concerning the installation (see https://autohotkey.com/download/):

> Note: The installer also includes an "extract to" function to extract
>   all files without installing. This can be accessed from the installer
>   GUI or on the command line.

Now, I was wondering what are the differences between a direct install as compared to just extracting the files? What vulnerabilities will an AutoHotkey installation introduce?

Comment: "What vulnerabilities will an AutoHotkey installation introduce?" What makes you think that the reason for this feature is to avoid introducing a vulnerability ?

Comment: @Stephane Strictly speaking, I never said that: I was asking *what the differences are* between the two. *Then* I asked what vulnerabilities could be introduced. I was just expecting that an installed AutoHotKey could maybe be advantageous for a malicious exe but I just wanted to make sure to make the right decision between the two options.

Comment: @Stephane So you are saying that there is no difference?

Comment: It is not a problem of vulnerability nor even security (so the question is rather off topic here, maybe better on superuser but unsure). It is about the difference between a full install (program goes on a fixed disk and is referenced in registry) and a [portable application install](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_application) where the program can reside on a removable media and be used *without installation* on any computer.